# Calling Methods From Class Not Working

Tags: python, class, methods

I have made a sonar finding game and some functions for it. I have put these functions into a class and now I want to call them so I can play the game, however when I define the class call it now returns things to me like game.getNewBoard() takes 0 positional arguments and tells me I have given it one when I have not and so on. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   # Sonar

import random
import sys
class OceanTreasure:
    def drawBoard(board):
        # Draw the board data structure.

        hline = '    ' # initial space for the numbers down the left side of the board
        for i in range(1, 6):
            hline += (' ' * 9) + str(i)

        # print the numbers across the top
        print(hline)
        print('   ' + ('0123456789' * 6))
        print()

        # print each of the 15 rows
        for i in range(15):
            # single-digit numbers need to be padded with an extra space
            if i < 10:
                extraSpace = ' '
            else:
                extraSpace = ''
            print('%s%s %s %s' % (extraSpace, i, getRow(board, i), i))

        # print the numbers across the bottom
        print()
        print('   ' + ('0123456789' * 6))
        print(hline)


    def getRow(board, row):
        # Return a string from the board data structure at a certain row.
        boardRow = ''
        for i in range(60):
            boardRow += board[i][row]
        return boardRow

    def getNewBoard():

        # Create a new 60x15 board data structure.
        board = []
        for x in range(60): # the main list is a list of 60 lists
            board.append([])
            for y in range(15): # each list in the main list has 15 single-character strings
                # I thought about using different char to make it more readble?? Admit it, it looks dull with just these ~
                if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
                    board[x].append('~')
                else:
                    board[x].append('~')
        return board

    def getRandomChests(numChests):
        # Create a list of chest data structures (two-item lists of x, y int coordinates)
        chests = []
        for i in range(numChests):
            chests.append([random.randint(0, 59), random.randint(0, 14)])
        return chests

    def isValidMove(x, y):
        # Return True if the coordinates are on the board, otherwise False.
        return x >= 0 and x <= 59 and y >= 0 and y <= 14

    def makeMove(board, chests, x, y):
        # Change the board data structure with a sonar device character. Remove treasure chests
        # from the chests list as they are found. Return False if this is an invalid move.
        # Otherwise, return the string of the result of this move.
        if not isValidMove(x, y):
            return False

        smallestDistance = 100 # any chest will be closer than 100.
        for cx, cy in chests:
            if abs(cx - x) > abs(cy - y):
                distance = abs(cx - x)
            else:
                distance = abs(cy - y)

            if distance < smallestDistance: # we want the closest treasure chest.
                smallestDistance = distance

        if smallestDistance == 0:
            # xy is directly on a treasure chest!
            chests.remove([x, y])
            return 'You have found a sunken treasure chest!'
        else:
            if smallestDistance < 10:
                board[x][y] = str(smallestDistance)
                return 'Treasure detected at a distance of %s from the sonar device.' % (smallestDistance)
            else:
                board[x][y] = 'O'
                return 'Sonar did not detect anything. All treasure chests out of range.'


    def enterPlayerMove():
        # Let the player type in her move. Return a two-item list of int xy coordinates.
        print('Where do you want to drop the next sonar device? (0-59 0-14) (or type quit)')
        while True:
            move = input()
            if move.lower() == 'quit':
                print('Thanks for playing!')
                sys.exit()

            move = move.split()
            if len(move) == 2 and move[0].isdigit() and move[1].isdigit() and isValidMove(int(move[0]), int(move[1])):
                return [int(move[0]), int(move[1])]
            print('Enter a number from 0 to 59, a space, then a number from 0 to 14.')


    def playAgain():
        # This function returns True if the player wants to play again, otherwise it returns False.
        print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
        return input().lower().startswith('y')



print('S O N A R !')
print()


while True:
    # game setup
    game=OceanTreasure()
    sonarDevices = 20
    theBoard = game.getNewBoard()
    theChests = getRandomChests(3)
    drawBoard(theBoard)
    previousMoves = []

    while sonarDevices > 0:
        # Start of a turn:

        # sonar device/chest status
        if sonarDevices > 1: extraSsonar = 's'
        else: extraSsonar = ''
        if len(theChests) > 1: extraSchest = 's'
        else: extraSchest = ''
        print('You have %s sonar device%s left. %s treasure chest%s remaining.' % (sonarDevices, extraSsonar, len(theChests), extraSchest))

        x, y = enterPlayerMove()
        previousMoves.append([x, y]) # we must track all moves so that sonar devices can be updated.

        moveResult = makeMove(theBoard, theChests, x, y)
        if moveResult == False:
            continue
        else:
            if moveResult == 'You have found a sunken treasure chest!':
                # update all the sonar devices currently on the map.
                for x, y in previousMoves:
                    makeMove(theBoard, theChests, x, y)
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            print(moveResult)

        if len(theChests) == 0:
            print('You have found all the sunken treasure chests! Congratulations and good game!')
            break

        sonarDevices -= 1

    if sonarDevices == 0:
        print('We\'ve run out of sonar devices! Now we have to turn the ship around and head')
        print('for home with treasure chests still out there! Game over.')
        print('    The remaining chests were here:')
        for x, y in theChests:
            print('    %s, %s' % (x, y))

    if not playAgain():
        sys.exit() #I thought this is a better way than just break or make false, correct me if I am wrong
```

Comment: There's no method named `getBoard`. You may also want to track the issue down to only a few lines of code.

Comment: as python doesn't really have oop, you need to accept self explicitly in any method:

Comment: e.g. def drawBoard(self, board). Though you better go and read documentation.

Comment: @TidB Sorry, I meant getNewBoard(). Either way, I stopped calling methods right away because I realized that it probably wouldn't work for the rest of them too. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every class method in Python receives the instance it is called from as the first parameter automatically. That means, that the first parameter is always `self`:

```
def drawBoard(self, board):
```

Comment: Thank you, however it also tells me getRow() is undefined when I call it within my class, even though I have self in it.

Comment: You have to call it with self: `self.getRow(board, row)`

Comment: you need to call it with `self.getRow()` in your class

Comment: Alright, everything works now, if only I  knew the simple solution was just writing self....